Error during exporting of image from Google Earth Engine to Google Drive through Jupyter Notebook
Trying to export a geoTIFF file from Google Earth Engine to my Google Drive using Python code. I'm running it on Jupyter Notebook.
The code works without error.
The problem is that the folder "TEST-IMAGE" appears on my drive except it is empty.
The code I'm using is as follows:
# Export clipped image to Gdrive



task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image=N_24_PARGANAS_viirs,
                                     scale=30,
                                     fileFormat='GeoTIFF',
                                     description='N24PGS_VIIRS_2022',
                                     folder='TEST-IMAGE',
                                     maxPixels=1e9)
task.start()

Please help me to find a solution? Do not hesitate to ask me for more details.

Overcame the problem by increasing pixel size.
